# SOAPUI for Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAPUI tool for Docusign REST API's. Any Ideas where can I add Integrator Key in this tool?

I tried but I was getting error as below:

```
{
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also removed non-constructive text. Please edit in to provide any additional detail and code that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't already done so, you'll need to login to the DocuSign web console and generate an integrator key (as described here: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/integrator_key.html).

Then simply specify authentication info (which includes Integrator Key) by using either the **HTTP Request Header** or the **SOAP Header** as described in the DocuSign SOAP API guide (https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/soap-api-guide.pdf) -- specifically, see the **Authentication** section, which starts on page 20. The SOAPUI documentation should specify the mechanics of setting either type of header -- the DocuSign documentation specifies the header format/contents.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,  I added as below headers with values  in SOAPUI, But I was receiving Error -->HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

[image]